# Adding logging to a complex function?

Tags: r, debugging, logging

Assume that I have a (at least subjectively) complex function like this:

```
library(rgithub)

pull <- function(i){
 commits <- get.pull.request.commits(owner = owner, repo = repo, id = i, ctx = get.github.context(), per_page=100)
 links <- digest_header_links(commits)
 number_of_pages <- links[2,]$page
 if (number_of_pages != 0)
   try_default(for (n in 1:number_of_pages){
    if (as.integer(commits$headers$`x-ratelimit-remaining`) < 5)
     Sys.sleep(as.integer(commits$headers$`x-ratelimit-reset`)-    as.POSIXct(Sys.time()) %>% as.integer())
  else
    get.pull.request.commits(owner = owner, repo = repo, id = i, ctx = get.github.context(), per_page=100, page = n)
}, default = NULL)
else 
   return(commits)
}

list <- c(500, 501, 502)

pull_lists <- lapply(list, pull)
```

Let's say that I want to attain a deeper understanding of what actually happens inside this function. How can I add some type of logging that will help me trace what goes on inside of the function as it is being run?

Comment: Do you need logging or would something like `browser()` work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use futile.logger

Than you can setup log threshold level using:

```
flog.threshold(INFO)
```

Functions, like flog.debug or flog.info are used to produce logging information

For further details see:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/better-logging-in-r-aka-futile-logger-1-3-0-released/

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/futile.logger/index.html